# How to organise/nest data for d3.js chart output

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, nested, hierarchical-data

I'm looking for some advice on how to effectively use large amounts of data with d3.js. Lets say for instance, I have this data set taken from a raw .csv file (converted from excel);

```
EA
,Jan_2016,Feb_2016,Mar_2016
Netherlands,11.7999,15.0526,13.2411
Belgium,25.7713,24.1374
France,27.6033,23.6186,20.2142

EB
,Jan_2016,Feb_2016,Mar_2016
Netherlands,1.9024,2.9456,4.0728
Belgium,-,6.5699,7.8894
France,5.3284,4.8213,1.471

EC
,Jan_2016,Feb_2016,Mar_2016
Netherlands,3.1499,3.1139,3.3284
Belgium,3.0781,4.8349,5.1596
France,16.3458,12.6975,11.6196
```

Using csv I guess the best way to represent this data would be something like;

```
Org,Country,Month,Score
EA,Netherlands,Jan,11.7999
EA,Belgium,Jan,27.6033
EA,France,Jan,20.2142
EA,Netherlands,Feb,15.0526
EA,Belgium,Feb,25.9374
EA,France,Feb,23.6186
EA,Netherlands,Mar,13.2411
EA,Belgium,Mar,24.1374
EA,France,Mar,20.2142
```

This seems very long winded to me, and would use up a lot of time. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this?

From what I can think of, I assume that JSON may be the more logical choice?

And for context of what kind of chart this data would go into, I would be looking to create a pie chart which can update the data depending on the country/month selected and comparing the three organisations scores each time.

(plnk to visualise)
http://plnkr.co/edit/P3loEGu4jMRpsvTOgCMM?p=preview

Thanks for any advice, I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: It depends on what you want to optimize... Disk usage? Simplicity of transforming from your original data? Fast loading? Reactive pie chart? Suitable for future additions?

Comment: Well they all sound essential! I suppose Simplicity of transforming from original data and being suitable for future additions are the most important.

Comment: Have you tried converting to the format you want ? The raw csv file you got from excel doesnt look correct. I mean if the values at the top of the excel sheet were dates, the countries on the left and values in between, shouldn't the first value (before Jan_2016) be empty ?

Comment: Yes - sorry for the confusion, I just removed it when writing the post, when I export the excel file to csv (by just using save as .csv) it does have the comma in front of the dates, I'll edit the post to put it back in - thanks

Comment: You need to add a name above the countries, for example, Countries ass you can't have an empty attribute. From there if you just use d3.csv("csvlink.csv", function(data){}) < data here will output the necessary values. See this example : http://plnkr.co/edit/cKrhGF4QRbzXRsjTDQoj?p=preview Then you can use it like any other data set in D3. Check the console log of the example. Is that what you want ?

Comment: As for how to lay it out, check this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 i dont think one pie chart will be a good idea. Maybe one for each country ? Or just to a timeseries multi line chart, so on the x axis are the months, the y axis is the value and the colour of the line (create a legend to show these ) is each country

Comment: Kind of - but the other issue is I want to compare the 3 different datasets, each one has a different heading but the same data layout. So the way the data appears in the console log is correct - but my concern is that I would have 3 identical data sets in the same csv file with no way to target each one individually, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the intermediary step you propose is a good one for keeping everything organized in memory. You don't have to go through a csv file though, you can just load your original csv file and turn it into an array of objects. Here is a parser:

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(error, dataTxt) { //import data file as text first
 var dataCsv=d3.csv.parseRows(dataTxt); //parseRows gives a 2D array
 var group=""; // the current group header ("organization")
 var times=[]; //the current month headers
 var data=[];  //the final data object, will be filled up progressively
 for (var i=0;i<dataCsv.length;i++) {
    if (dataCsv[i].length==1 ) { //group name
       if ( dataCsv[i][0] == "") 
          i++; //remove empty line
       group = dataCsv[i][0]; //get group name
       i++;
       times = dataCsv[i];//get list of time headings for this group 
       times.shift(); // (shift out first empty element)
     } else {
       country=dataCsv[i].shift(); //regular row: get country name
       dataCsv[i].forEach(function(x,j){ //enumerate values
         data.push({ //create new data item
           Org: group,  
           Country: country,
           Month: times[j],
           Score: x
         })
       }) 
    }
 }
```

This gives the following data array:

```
data= [{"Org":"EA","Country":"Netherlands","Month":"Jan_2016","Score":"11.7999"},
       {"Org":"EA","Country":"Netherlands","Month":"Feb_2016","Score":"15.0526"}, ...]
```

This is IMO the most versatile structure you can have. Not the best for memory usage though.

A simple way to nest this is the following:

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Month+"-"+d.Country; })
  .map(data);
```

It will give a map with key-values such as:

```
"Jan_2016-Netherlands":[{"Org":"EA","Country":"Netherlands","Month":"Jan_2016","Score":"11.7999"},{"Org":"EB","Country":"Netherlands","Month":"Jan_2016","Score":"1.9024"},{"Org":"EC","Country":"Netherlands","Month":"Jan_2016","Score":"3.1499"}]
```

Use `entries` instead of `map`to have an array instead of a map, and use a `rollup` function if you want to simplify the data by keeping only the array of scores. At this point it is rather straightforward to plug it into any d3 drawing  tool.

PS: a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YT6YFSuEwi6QrwGMsC8C?p=preview) with the running code of this script. Everything is shown in the console.

Comment: Hi - this makes a lot of sense! Thanks alot :) I'm trying to put it into action, in a static pie chart but I think i'm still struggling to understand how to use script you've created. Here is the plnk so far - hopefully i'm not a million miles away. http://plnkr.co/edit/1fiXFyl4MFZRrZX7DRCl?p=preview

Comment: Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/P2NvhAa6qrNkkvuA2Zvq?p=preview See the comments in the code.

Comment: Ah yes, it's becoming clearer! I've finished it (mostly) if you'd like to take a look - http://plnkr.co/edit/hLBoPsnqeTKwvpXwMJPm?p=preview, I think it's okay? or do you think there could be a better way to structure the code? Also, was wondering if you could offer any pointers on how to get the chart to transition on load? (sorry for repeat comments! Let me know if it's against the rules)

Comment: Suggestion: use a function that does the drawing with a delay for any key. On load, draw first with dummy data, then call the drawing function for the starting key. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kli6w2VUUAUa1w8UynRB?p=preview

Comment: Ah yes okay, that makes a lot more sense. I'm trying to label each segment with the organisation name, which I thought would be easy to do. However, I'm finding it to be very confusing. From what I can see, I have to separate the chart into slices ([plnk of progress](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPaNjKMrEVPwKLoTwbFY?p=preview)) However, I don't know how I would get the Org data into the return function? Sorry for the frequent questions, maybe I should start a new question up?